# Get all texts of last childs in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div>
      text 1
  </div>
  <p>
    text 2
  </p>
  <p>
    <a>
      text 3
    </a>
    text 4
  </p>
</nav>
```

How can I get an array like this with JQuery :
    `['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4']`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var pTxtNode = $('p').map(function(){
  return $(this).text().trim()
}).get();
console.log(pTxtNode)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <p>
      text 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    text 2
  </p>
  <p>
    <a>
      text 3
    </a>
    text 4
  </p>
</nav>
```

You can use `.map()` with `.get()`:

```
$('p').map(function(){
  return $(this).text()
}).get();
```

Also, If you want to include text nodes that are outside p tag, use `.contents` with `.filter` function:

```
 $('nav').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ; //3
 });;
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my question and removed the first p tag, I want every text inside nav split in an array. Maybe I should use your second option with contents and filter but I don't see how to convert it in an array.

Comment: Yes. you need to use second approach

Comment: Thanks, I just don't know how to convert it as an array. Any hint?